# How can I select all the li child of an element in js

Tags: javascript, dom

How can I select all the li child of an element in js

I want to select all the li elements of this item (direct child, grand child all)

````
document.querySelectorAll(".stellarnav li.has-sub").forEach(item =>{
    item.addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log(item)
        // to make you understand I described it below in css language
        // in CSS language it is like this: item li

        // then I want to removeAttribute from the all the child
        // like this
        document.querySelectorAll(`${item} li`).forEach(childItem =>{
            childItem.removeAttribute("open");
        })
        // how can I achive this thing to select all the li childs
        // here I tried it but this is not valid
    })
});```
````

Comment: what's this Lorem ipsum ?? why you placed the dummy text ?? did you try 
this.getElementsByTagName("li") ?

Comment: sorry The question required more description, but I have nothing more to describe so I added that lorem ipsum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run `this.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(li=>li.removeAttribute("open"));`

This is a document [querySelectorAll document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Tested code:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".nav li.has-sub").forEach(item =>{
      
  item.addEventListener("click", function(){
      this.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(li=>li.removeAttribute("open"));
  })
})
```

```css
li[open]{
  color: red;
}
.nav >li{
  margin: 10px
}
```

```html
<ul class='nav'>
  <li class='has-sub'>
     this is has-sub li 1
    <ul>
      <li open>
        this is open
      </li>
      <li open>
        this is open
      </li>
      <li>   this is another li
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='has-sub'>
     this is has-sub li 2
    <ul>
      <li open>
        this is open
      </li>
      <li open>
        this is open
      </li>
      <li> this is another li
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
     this is li 3
    <ul>
      <li open>
        this is not has-sub open
      </li>
      <li open>
       this is not has-sub open
      </li>
      <li>  this is another li
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I am really grateful to you. So many thanks for quick response and giving your valuable time.